# Creating a date/datetime variable within a string in PL/SQL without using concatenation

Tags: c#, oracle

I get the ORA-01036 error whenever I try to write a string concatenated with a function of `TO_CHAR` type.

After reading stefan.schwetschke's answer on [ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number when running query through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375288/ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number-when-running-query-through-c-sharp)

I realized I might be having some concatenation issues after having tried:

```
SELECT 
'Please output this date ' || TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
FROM dual
```

Is there any way of setting a variable within the string avoiding both the use of concatenation and of the DBMS_ASSERT package ?

The expected output is today's date with the time in this format:

```
please output this date 04-03-2019 16:30
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The SQL you posted works just fine. If you're having an issue within a PL/SQL block, or from a C# connector, please post the details on those and the exact code that's failing.

Comment: have you tried adding an alias to that column?